# How to filter a query by property of user profile in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have two models,`Design` and `Profile`. Profile is hooked up in settings.py as the profile to be used with the User model. So I can access it via `user.get_profile()`.

And each `Design` instance has an `author` property that is a ForeignKey to User.

So, when I'm any view, I can get the screenname (a property of Profile) by:

`user.get_profile().screenname`

But what is the syntax to SEARCH BY FILTER for this property? What I currently have:

`designs = Design.objects.filter(author__userprofile__screenname__icontains=w)`

This doesn't work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your profile class is named Profile, and you haven't customized the User <-> Profile relation using the related_name property of the ForeignKey, then shouldn't you be accessing via:

```
designs = Design.objects.filter(author__user__profile__screenname__icontains=w)
```

The User -> Profile spans a relation so you need the extra double underscores.

Comment: Close. I needed to do: author__profile__screenname. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not sure if this has changed, but for me (using Django 1.3) I had to use _____userprofile_____ and not _____profile_____

Comment: @mhost It depends on how you name your user profile class, since it's not a built in model. This will work for any model with a OneToOneField pointing to the User model